# Rails 6 page looking for pre-compiled version of application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm trying to start a brand new Rails 6 app and running into an issue where the page is looking for the pre-compiled version of my application.js.

```
GET http://localhost:3001/packs/js/application-b228a72fc69e7d5d249f.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Commands I've run to reproduce:

```
rails new myapp -d postgresql --skip-turbolinks
# Create a controller/view called IndexController and index.html.erb
# add `root "index#index" to routes.rb
rails db:create
rails s
```

I get a Rails error at that point showing `Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError` and fix that by running:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rails assets:clobber
yarn
rails assets:precompile
```

Finally, the page loads (it's just a blank page) but in the JS console I have an error:

`GET http://localhost:3001/packs/js/application-b228a72fc69e7d5d249f.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

```
Rails 6.1.0
Ruby 2.7.1p83
Node v15.5.0
Yarn 1.22.10
```

Is there anything else I can try to get this resolved?